# how to implement load balancer in mule Http Endpoint

Tags: mule, mule-studio

In simple http endpoint, how to implement load balancer using any point studio.

```
<flow name="testFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration"/>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In simple mule HTTP endpoint you cant achieve load balancing.
However there are other efficient solution for achieving load balancing in mule application.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/dedicated-load-balancer-tutorial
http://www.slideshare.net/ramakrishnakapa/load-balancer-in-mule

Answer (score 0):

Load balancing can not be in simple http endpoint, but you can deploy several instances of your application and balance your request among those instances in mule. Switching between those instances is matter of different algorithms.
In this post it is all described in detail.
https://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/mule-dev/load-balancing-with-mule/